# rsync doesn't work in Python script: rsync: change_dir failed: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: python, linux, rsync

I need to transfer a directory (and all its content in it) to a remote host using `rsync` and I need to use it inside a python script but I got this following error:

```
building file list ... 
rsync: change_dir "/home/xxxx//xxxx/xxxx/ root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/opt/customized" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 20 bytes  received 11 bytes  62.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]
```

The Python cmd I use:

```
HOST_PASSWORD="xxxx"
filepath="xxxx/xxxx/"
ip="xx.xx.xx.xx"
DEPLOY_DIR="/opt/customized/"
subprocess.call(['rsync', '-Kavz', '--exclude=*.py', '--chown=root:root','--delete-after','--rsh="/usr/bin/sshpass -p {} ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -l root"'.format(HOST_PASSWORD),'{} root@{}:{}'.format(filepath, ip, DEPLOY_DIR)])
```

However, I can use this `rsync` cmd in the terminal **no problem**:

```
rsync -Kavz --exclude=*.py --chown=root:root --delete-after --rsh="/usr/bin/sshpass -p xxxx ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -l root" xxxx/xxxx/ root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/opt/customized/
```

What goes wrong in my Python script? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to put quotes after `--rsh=` in the argument list. That's needed to keep it as a single argument in the shell, but in `subprocess.call()` each list element is already a single argument, and embedded quotes are treated literally.

And the source and destination filenames should be separate arguments, not a single string `{} root@{}:{}`

```
subprocess.call([
    'rsync', '-Kavz', '--exclude=*.py', '--chown=root:root',
    '--delete-after',
    '--rsh=/usr/bin/sshpass -p {} ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -l root'.format(HOST_PASSWORD), 
    filepath, 'root@{}:{}'.format(ip, DEPLOY_DIR)
])
```

There's also a [`pyrsync`](https://pypi.org/project/pyrsync/) library you could use instead of invoking the `rsync` command in a subprocess.